# Firebase security rules for Firebase events

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I'm trying to set up security rules for my cloud firestore, but I'm confused about which database the rules should apply to.

The only feature I currently use is logging Firebase events. Do the security rules apply to Firebase events? If so, for which database should rules be written? And if not, can I deny read/write access to all and the events will still be logged and sent to BigQuery?

Comment: Quick answer below, but it sounds like we're dealing with a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What are you trying to accomplish by setting up security rules for Cloud Firestore?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Thanks! Yes, that's what I suspected because all the documentation I read didn't seem to apply to me. The reason I was setting up security rules is because I got that email saying that my test rules are expiring :).

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. As far as I know that email should only be sent when your database was used. Have you used the database at all?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen The only "database" I used is Firebase events. Basically, all I've done is link Firebase events to BigQuery, and added some queries in BQ to analyze Firebase events. Is that the database you refer to?

Comment: "Firebase events" is not a product, which is where part of my confusion came from. But if you've only used Analytics, then you can safely ignore that email (and probably shouldn't have gotten it to begin with).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're using [Google Analytics for Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics) to [log events](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events). There are no server-side security rules that affect either the logging of these events, nor their export to BigQuery.